# c# - using SelectMany to merge multiple lists

Tags: c#, linq, merge

As of right now, I use the following code to merge two `List<string>` lists and order them by a timestamp

```
var list = report[0];  
var list2 = report[1];
var result = list
    .Union(list2)
    .Select(x =>
    {  return new {Log = x, Time = TimeSpan.Parse(x.Split(' ')[0])}; })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Time)
    .ToList();
```

The issue now is that I have to handle more than two lists, up to `n`. I have looked into the `SelectMany` examples but it does not seem to be supporting the same functionality as `Select` does. Another way I was planning to do this was using `foreach` loop but it does not seem to be an efficient way, especially if the list get bigger.
**Edit (added sample data and expected result):**
An example list1 can look something like this:
`11:03:01:003 INFO some event has occurred
11:03:31:004 DEBUG another event has occurred
11:04:01:015 INFO third event has occurred`
An example list2 can look something like this:
`11:03:16:003 INFO fourth event has occurred
11:03:32:025 DEBUG fifth event has occurred
11:03:54:023 INFO sixth event has occurred`
And, therefore, there can multiple lists like that. An expected merge of these two lists will look the following way:
`11:03:01:003 INFO some event has occurred
11:03:16:003 INFO fourth event has occurred
11:03:31:004 DEBUG another event has occurred
11:03:32:025 DEBUG fifth event has occurred
11:03:54:023 INFO sixth event has occurred
11:04:01:015 INFO third event has occurred`

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Can't you just do `list1.Union(list2).Union(list3).Union(list4)` and so on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *can* use `SelectMany` here:

```
// suppose reports is of type List<List<SomeClass>>
reports.SelectMany(x => x)
    .Select(x =>
        {  return new {Log = x, Time = TimeSpan.Parse(x.Split(' ')[0])}; })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Time)
    .ToList();
```

Adding a `.Distinct` call will make it have the same effect as `Union`:

```
reports.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct()
    .Select(x =>
        {  return new {Log = x, Time = TimeSpan.Parse(x.Split(' ')[0])}; })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Time)
    .ToList();
```

Alternatively, keep using `Union`:

```
IEnumerable<SomeClass> query = reports[0];
for (int i = 1 ; i < reports.Length ; i++) {
   query = query.Union(reports[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `report` is an `IEnumerable` of `IEnumerable<string>`. So you need something like this:

```
report.SelectMany(l => l.Select(x => new {Log = x, Time = TimeSpan.Parse(x.Split(' ')[0])}))
    .OrderBy(x => x.Time)
    .ToList();
```

`SelectMany` will union all results of the `l.Select`, then you order them by time.

EDIT:

Since it was pointed out that `Union` removes duplicates, you need to add `Distinct` to get the same result:

```
report.SelectMany(l => l.Select(x => new {Log = x, Time = TimeSpan.Parse(x.Split(' ')[0])}))
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(x => x.Time)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: `Union` removes duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions for this, one of them could be:

```
List<IEnumerable<string>> allLists = new List<IEnumerable<string>>();
            allLists.Add(report[0]);
            allLists.Add(report[1]);
            allLists.Add(report[2]);

            var result = allLists.SelectMany(l => l.Select(x => new
            {
                Log = x,
                Time = TimeSpan.Parse(x.Split(' ')[0])
            })).OrderBy(x => x.Time)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: `Union` removes duplicates.

Comment: As far as I could tell, the author says report[0] is a List<string> as well as report[1]. He can, indeed, work directly on report (if it his an IEnumerable) directly instead of creating an allLists variable.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why the other answers have extra `.Select` :

```
var result = report
       .SelectMany(l => l, (l, x) => new { Log = x, Time = TimeSpan.Parse(x.Split(' ')[0]) })
       .Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.Time).ToList();
```

Comment: Because members of `report` are clearly Enumerables of strings.

Comment: `report` is an `IEnumerable<List<string>>` (according to the OP: *"I use the following code to merge two `List<string>` lists"*), so in your code `x` is a `List<string>`, and you can't do `x.Split()`. You have to first flatten all the lists into a single list, which is what `.SelectMany()` does, and *then* you can do `.Select()` on it.

Comment: Still not right though, does not remove duplicates like `Union` does.